# Libreoffice Calc - Can you save VBA code after viewing and editing, so it is saved next time file is accessed?

Tags: linux-mint, libreoffice, development

I am developing using VBA in Libreoffice Calc. I found out via experimenting that it can read `vbaproject` in a `.xlsm` file.

I was able to read macros under vbaproject I had created via Excel, saved this file as a `.xls` file after edits, then closed the file and then Calc.

I expected the new file to be saved with the changes, but on reopening the file later, there were no modules visible under `vbaproject` which I thought shouldn't happen.

Can you save VBA code after viewing and editing, so it is saved and viewable next time file is accessed?

Comment: What version of LibreOffice?

Comment: Unsure. It would be version that comes with linux mint v17. I will find out.

Comment: It tells the verison in Help -> About LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to a newer version of LibreOffice.  With LO 5.1.6.2 on Ubuntu, I downloaded [datavalcombo_addsortmulticol.xlsm](http://www.contextures.com/excelfiles.html), made a change under VBAProject and on sheet 1, then saved as `.xlsm`.  The new document kept the changes.

With Apache OpenOffice 4.1.3 however, the macros did not work correctly, and apparently AOO cannot save in .xlsm format.

Comment: I have updated my question - I initially saved it as an `.xls` file. How about saving yours as an `.xls` file - can you replicate problem?

Comment: The changes still worked correctly when saved as `.xls`. Does the problem occur with the example file from the link above?